# Reading from S3 location with dynamic addition of files through java client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket and files are being to the bucket by an ever running process. Now I want to write a consumer of these using java aws-s3-sdk. How to make sure, every file is read exactly once?

Comment: Do you use S3 notification to trigger your consumer?

Comment: No, the consumer can poll periodically, Consumer is basically an Oozie coordinator.

Comment: In either case case you would have to store the current state between execution. For example, you could put all the files processes in DynamoDB. Then use the information from there to process only new files.